# Who is this in the Asylum of the Daleks?

Tags: doctor-who

This probably cannot be answered until the new season starts (right now it is August 2012, and it starts in September), but who is the second redhead in this image?

[image: Daleks]?

Comment: I'd imagine it was Amy pond.

Comment: @Pureferret the one in the heels is **shorter** than the other one!

Comment: Dude, *time travel*. Younger Amy.

Comment: http://imgur.com/0QCyk

Comment: @dlanod True, no upvote from me until this is answerable.

Comment: @Pureferret I am purrrrfectly fine with that ^_^

Comment: It does my heart good to see all those Daleks come together for some galaxy smashing.

Comment: Unfortunately this is at the time unanswerable and in the future will be general reference. So I must vote to close.

Comment: Actually it is answerable now. [The](http://goo.gl/DK7Ns) [episode](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/tvandradio/doctor-who/9475370/Doctor-Who-Asylum-of-the-Daleks-spoiler-free-first-review.html) [has](http://doctorwhotv.co.uk/asylum-of-the-daleks-spoiler-free-review-37597.htm) [been](http://www.guardian.co.uk/tv-and-radio/tvandradioblog/2012/aug/15/doctor-who-asylum-of-the-daleks) [screened](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2012/08/doctor-whos-day-roundup-6/). We just need someone from one of those screenings to answer it.

Comment: @dlanod vote to reopen?

Comment: Why didn't she appear in the episode?

Comment: @JDoe Why didn't who appear where?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After gathering the cast information for Asylum of the Daleks, the identity of the other woman is Anamaria Marinca playing the role of Darla. This is found through deduction. Follow:

- There are only three women in the episode.
- Karen Gillian is 5'11" tall and is wearing flats on the right.
- Naomi Ryan (my first guess) is 5'9" tall.
- Anamaria Marinca is 5'7" tall.

Our mystery woman is wearing shoes with heels (my wife estimates at least 3 inches high) and is still shorter than Gillian. So, if my wife's guess is correct, she would still be at least one inch shorter than Gillian Using deduction, I am forced to conclude Anamaria Marinca is the woman in this picture.

**Asylum of the Daleks:** Written by Steven Moffat. Directed by Nick Hurran

**Cast:** Matt Smith (The Doctor), Karen Gillan (Amy Pond), Arthur Darvill (Rory Pond-Williams), Anamaria Marinca (Darla), David Gyasi (Harvey), Barnaby Edwards (Dalek Operator), Nicholas Briggs (Voice of the Daleks), Naomi Ryan (Cassandra)

Comment: To be fair, OP did ask who it was without specifying if he wanted the actress or the character. But since Moffat wrote the episode, it's probably a new character.

Comment: also, by her bare arms the actress is clearly caucasian, which Anamaria Marinca is and Naomi Ryan is not.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Shhh! There's inductions happening!

Comment: *sneaky* how not one of the cast lists I saw before the episode included Jenna Louise Coleman in them.

Comment: I found that a bit sneaky as well. I saw well over ten different lists and none said anything about her in THIS episode. Only that she would show up later in the season. I wonder if she will be the same character...Probably not. Now that would be a sight, a former Dalek working with the Doctor...